# A simple proof of Jordan curve theorem

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

I need a short proff of the Jordan curve theorem please.

The one I have is 16 pages long and is for a little expo, so I need one a little shorter.

Thanks

Comment: See J. Dieudonne, Foundations of modern analysis. AP. -New York & London. 1960, Appendix to Ch.9 to this end. It takes approximately 5 p.

Comment: This proof takes about 2 pages, not including the proof of Brouwer’s fixed-point theorem: https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/class750/section5.pdf . Actually, it comes from https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1984.11971517 .

Comment: The proof from the Dieudonne's book is all-sufficient.

Comment: If it's for exposition, consider proving it just for pl curves. The general proof covers non-rectifiable curves, so by conservation of difficulty it's either going to involve heavy machinery like Brouwer or it's going to be long and involved.